# How to display an alert only once when user click anywhere

Tags: onclick, alert

I am using javascript and I need to display an alert only once when the user click anywhere in the site. But make sure it will not pop up everytime the user click anywhere.

Im not professional but I need this code to embed in my e-commerce site. I have tried a regular onload alert. but it will show once the page is loaded. then i tried this automatic code:

```
</html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

document.onclick = myClickHandler;


function myClickHandler() {
  alert("All orders require minimum two weeks notice due to the nature of event and   wedding products");
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
   </html>
```

and works, but every time I click appear and that is annoying. I need a onclick event, anywhere in the page... to display an alert only once. to advise the user about important info.

Desperatly need some solution. Thanks

Comment: a) What have you tried? We aren't going to do your work for you, please have a go yourself, and if you come across any specific problems please show your code and we will try to help. b) What language(s) are you using? Please edit the tags on your question to reflect this (and check if "clickonce" is really a tag you want based on its description) because as it stands your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
      $(document).on('click.once', function () {
          alert("Alerted once");
          $(document).off('click.once');
      })            
 });
```

This makes use of the .off() and named event feature in jQuery.

[.off feature](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

[event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Comment: should i include this part within a secific html code?